# How to make text flash different colors in a C# console application?

Tags: c#

I have this program
http://pastebin.com/uHNi15pW

I want this code to flash all of the colors avalible

```
Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!");
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: Just set the [`Console.ForegroundColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.foregroundcolor(v=vs.110).aspx) property?

Answer (score 3):

To do this, you will need to know the position of the text on the console (because `Console.WriteLine` will simply write at the current cursor position). You can do something like this:

```
public async Task ShowTextInColors(string text, int x, int y, int delay, CancellationToken token)
{
    ConsoleColor[] colors = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConsoleColor)).OfType<ConsoleColor>().ToArray();

    int color = -1;
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        color += 1;
        if (color >= colors.Length) color = 0;
        Console.CursorLeft = x;
        Console.CursorTop = y;
        Console.ForegroundColor = colors[color];
        Console.Write(text);
        await Task.Delay(delay, token);
    }
}
```

`x` and `y` determine the cursor position on the console at which you want to display the text.

You can call this like that:

```
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
ShowTextInColors("Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!", 0, 10, 1000, source.Token);
```

and eventually stop it by calling

```
source.Cancel();
```

Note that this will interfer with other calls to `Console.*` methods in other threads. And since your question looks like you want to display a tic tac toe game below that line, you may need to synchronize your `Console.*` calls. But synchronization would be a new question and you will surely find a lot of them on StackOverflow (try `lock` keyword).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
            while (true)
            {
                foreach (ConsoleColor c in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConsoleColor)))
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = c;
                    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!");
                    Console.Clear();
                }
            }
```

You can add some deley in foreach to set slow down blinking

```
          while (true)
            {
                foreach (ConsoleColor c in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConsoleColor)))
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = c;
                    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000); // 1 sec. deley
                    Console.Clear();
                }
            }
```

**If You want something without`Console.Clear()`** try this: You must set the positions of X and Y

```
Console.WriteLine("Some text"); // this text will stay when tesxt "Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!" will by blinking

 while (true)
    {
        foreach (ConsoleColor c in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConsoleColor)))
        {
            Console.CursorLeft = 4; // set position
            Console.CursorTop = 6; // set position
            Console.ForegroundColor = c;
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!");

        }
    }
```

In Your code You must paste code like this befeore `do` loop:

```
var task = new Task(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    foreach (ConsoleColor c in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConsoleColor)))
                    {
                        var x = Console.CursorLeft;
                        var y = Console.CursorTop;

                        Console.CursorLeft = 0; // set position
                        Console.CursorTop = 0; // set position

                        Console.ForegroundColor = c;
                        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!");

                        Console.CursorLeft = x;
                        Console.CursorTop = y;

                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
                }

                });

do
{
.... rest of code
```

And change this, after Board create:

```
                Board();// calling the board Function

                if (task.Status != TaskStatus.Running)
                {
                    task.Start();
                }

                choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//Taking users choice
```

Full code You have here

https://github.com/przemekwa/ProgramingStudy/blob/master/ProgramingStudy/Study/TikTakTou.cs

And effect will by blinking sign while You play.

Comment: I tried the one with the console.clear but the rest of the program dosent show up

Comment: I Update my answer -- last example is without`Console.Clear`

Comment: sorry to bother but im still getting the same issue

Comment: Hey, I copy paste Your code, it is working great. Where You want to put the blinking text? When the player win or when?

Comment: No, at the top of the program

Comment: @FFIX I Update my answer